# Recurrence relation for sum of powers of roots of a cubic equation.

Tags: recurrence-relations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^3 −s_1x^2 +s_2x−s_3 = (x−α)(x−β)(x−γ) ∈ \mathbb{Q}[x]$ where $α, β, γ ∈ \mathbb{C}$.
Denoting $σ_i = α^
i +β^
i +γ^
i$
for $i ≥ 0$, show that $σ_0 = 3, σ_1 = s_1$ and $σ_2 = s^2_1
−2s-2.$

Show further that
$σ_r = s_1σ_{r−1} − s_2σ_{r−2} + s_3σ_{r−3}$ for $r \geq 3$.

It was easy enough to get the results for $σ_0,σ_1$ and $σ_2$, but I'm struggling to see how I can get the further result. Presumably it's by induction but I can't even get the base case of $r=3$, never mind the next step.

Am I missing an obvious trick? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The roots satisfies the polynomial and you can multiply the polynomial with the same root as many time as you want.

Comment: Are you aware of [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand
$$\begin{align}s_1σ_{r−1} − s_2σ_{r−2} + s_3σ_{r−3}&=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha^{r-1}+\beta^{r-1}+\gamma^{r-1})\\&\quad{}-(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)(\alpha^{r-2}+\beta^{r-2}+\gamma^{r-2})\\
&\quad{}+\alpha\beta\gamma(\alpha^{r-3}+\beta^{r-3}+\gamma^{r-3})\\
&=\alpha^r+\beta^r+\gamma^r+(\alpha^{r-1}\beta+\alpha^{r-1}\gamma+\beta^{r-1}\alpha+\cdots)\\
&\quad{}-(\alpha^{r-1}\beta+\alpha^{r-1}\gamma+\cdots)-(\alpha^{r-2}\beta\gamma+\cdots)\\
&\quad{}+\alpha^{r-2}\beta\gamma+\cdots\\&=\alpha^r+\beta^r+\gamma^r\end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

Recurrence relationship:

$$s_1σ_{k-1} − s_2σ_{k−2} + s_3σ_{k-3}=σ_k \tag{1}$$

can be obtained in a **direct, "heuristic" way**. Let us start for that from the following identity valid for any root $x$ of the given polynomial :

$$ s_1x^2 − s_2x +s_3 =x^3$$

Multiplying LHS and RHS by $x^{k-3}$, we get:

$$s_1x^{k-1} − s_2x^{k-2} + s_3x^{k-3}=x^{k}.\tag{2}$$

Writing (2) for the different roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and summing up these 3 equations, one gets (1).